# How do I plot a contour plot of 3 column data

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, contour

I have a 3 column irregular data in the format [X Y Z]. I am having difficulty in creating a `contourf`
plot for the same since it requires one to create a meshgrid and also that data be uniform among the grid.

I need some direction or hint to get started.

Comment: I don't know what is wrong with my question, to get a downvote. If it needs some improvement please atleast leave a comment explaining the reason behind the downvote, so I  can update/elaborate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am providing two ways in which you can create a contour/density plot for the data which is in 3-column format and irregular, as you have mentioned.

1. You can use Mathematica: see the documentation of [ListDensityPlot](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListDensityPlot.html). You can directly provide the data as, `ListDensityPlot[{{x1,y1,f1},…,{xk,yk,fk}}]`, and this will plot the sought density plot.
2. There is also a simple way to do this in python: You can see the documentation of [tricontourf](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.tricontourf.html), a module of matplotlib. Its functionality is similar to that of `contourf`, except that you give 1D arrays rather than the data in mesh grid format.

Comment: This is helpful, I will both approaches. Thanks!